# How to pass parameters without using url

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have number of values.
I need to pass these values to another page without using the `window.location`

```
function sample(cID){
    var clg = ${param.clg};
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "sampleShow?clg="+clg+"&cID="+cID+"&level="+level,
        dataType : "json",
        cache : false,
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success : function(response) {
            window.location= "cc"
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            console.log("error"+xhr.status);
        },
        complete : function() {
        }
    });
}
```

This is my controller ajax function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sampleShow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String showc(HttpServletRequest request,Model  model)
{
    model.addAttribute("ccID", request.getParameter("cID"));
    model.addAttribute("clg", request.getParameter("clg"));
    model.addAttribute("level", request.getParameter("level"));

    return "{\"sucess\":\"true\"}";
}
```

I need to get the values in cc page.

Comment: Why have you set dataType : "json"? Do you want to send json data or it's just string data?

Comment: @sudarshan_SMD just a string data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call should like:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "sampleShow",            
        data :  {clg: clg, cID: cID, level: level },            
        success : function(response) {
            window.location= "cc"
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            console.log("error"+xhr.status);
        },
        complete : function() {
        }
    });
```

No need to specify dataType: "json", as you are not sending json. Data is passed using 'data'. Refere [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

You can also use shorthand method [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), to post instead of jQuery.ajax()

You may also like to read on [what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).